Selection of a row based on contents of multiple columns in Excel
I found part of the solution here:
Excel vba - find row number where colum data (multiple clauses)
What I am interested in is the selection of the row instead of a message box with the inoformation. I need the code to just select the required cells so that the data can be moved to another position and the space created is then deleted.
Here is the code from the other stackoverflow post with my modifications:
Sub EquivalenceMove()
'
' EquivalenceMove Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+O
'
    
    Dim rngFound As Range
    Dim strFirst As String
    Dim strNaN As String
    Dim strBlank As String

    strNaN = "NaN"
    strBlank = ""

    Set rngFound = Columns("B").Find(strNaN, Cells(Rows.Count, "B"), xlValues, xlWhole)
    If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
        strFirst = rngFound.Address
        Do
            If LCase(Cells(rngFound.Row, "C").Text) = LCase(strBlank) Then
                'Found a match
                MsgBox "Found a match at: " & rngFound.Row & Chr(10) & _
                       "Value in column D: " & Cells(rngFound.Row, "D").Text & Chr(10) & _
                       "Value in column F: " & Cells(rngFound.Row, "F").Text
                Range("ArngFound.Row:GrngFound.Row").Select
            End If
            Set rngFound = Columns("B").Find(strNaN, rngFound, xlValues, xlWhole)
        Loop While rngFound.Address <> strFirst
    End If

    Set rngFound = Nothing
    
    Selection.Cut Destination:=Range("M4:S6")
    Columns("A:G").Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=0
End Sub

I added Range("ArngFound.Row:GrngFound.Row").Select after the MsgBox entry to try to select what I need to, but I obviously lack the knowledge to call for that information properly and I'm not sure how to find it.
Running the code gives "Found a match at: 19", for example, and would ideally select columns A-G in row 19 for the last bit of code to use.

Range(Cells(rowNum,startColumn),Cells(rowNum,endColumn)) should be a very strong start, which uses a different syntax than Range("A2") [think Cells(2,1)].

In general, it is recommended to avoid using Select in VBA where possible.  With that said, you can use the Intersect Method to get at the data you're interested in:
Intersect(Range("A:G"), rngFound.EntireRow).Select

However, instead of Select, you can just copy/paste the data directly, and then delete the cells where it was found:
With Intersect(Range("A:G"), rngFound.EntireRow)
    .Copy Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    .Delete xlShiftUp
End With

Also, the post referenced is an old one of mine, and it doesn't have fully qualified range references which means the sheet references are missing. Here's an updated version of the same code where it doesn't have the msgbox, does include the data move, and also has the worksheet references:
Sub EquivalenceMove()
'
' EquivalenceMove Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+O
'
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngFound As Range
    Dim rngDelete As Range
    Dim strFirst As String
    Dim strNaN As String
    Dim strBlank As String
    
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    strNaN = "NaN"
    strBlank = ""

    Set rngFound = ws.Columns("B").Find(strNaN, ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B"), xlValues, xlWhole)
    If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
        strFirst = rngFound.Address
        Do
            If LCase(ws.Cells(rngFound.Row, "C").Text) = LCase(strBlank) Then
                'Found a match
                With Intersect(ws.Range("A:G"), rngFound.EntireRow)
                    .Copy ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                    If rngDelete Is Nothing Then
                        Set rngDelete = .Cells
                    Else
                        Set rngDelete = Union(rngDelete, .Cells)
                    End If
                End With
            End If
            Set rngFound = ws.Columns("B").Find(strNaN, rngFound, xlValues, xlWhole)
        Loop While rngFound.Address <> strFirst
    End If

    Set rngFound = Nothing
    If Not rngDelete Is Nothing Then rngDelete.Delete xlShiftUp
    
End Sub


Thanks for your help from the past and present. Is there way to specify the paste destination? It is very nice how the code will add the next selection after the first, however, it is currently pasting the data in row 12 since there is other data below where the data being selected is supposed to go (M4:S4)

The range object provided after .Copy is the destination, so you can specify a destination there.
